# Screen width in React Native

Tags: react-native

How do I get screen width in React native?
I need it because I use some absolute components that overlap and their position on screen changes with different devices.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

In React-Native we have an Option called Dimensions

Include Dimensions at the top var where you have include the Image,and Text and other components.

Then in your Stylesheets you can use as below,

```
ex: {
width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
height: Dimensions.get('window').height
}
```

In this way you can get the device window and height.

Comment: How can I use this if I want to make the sum of 2 components width to equal the `Dimensions.get('window').width`?

Comment: Just save these values globally and use it anywhere is not safe when your device is rotated. I recommend using [react hooks](https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks#usedimensions) in function components

Comment: This answer is outdated, see answer of @micnguyen below.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61134698/3161534

Answer (score 107):

Simply declare this code to get device width

```
let deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width
```

---

Maybe it's obviously but, Dimensions is an react-native import

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'
```

Dimensions will not work without that

Comment: Thank you! People on stack overflow leave out where their imports are coming from too often. Thanks for including it, that's exactly what I needed. Its not in the official docs.

Answer (score 37):

**April 10th 2020 Answer:**

The suggested answer using `Dimensions` is now discouraged. See: https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions

The recommended approach is using the `useWindowDimensions` hook in React; https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions which uses a hook based API and will also update your value when the screen value changes (on screen rotation for example):

```
import {useWindowDimensions} from 'react-native';

const windowWidth = useWindowDimensions().width;
const windowHeight = useWindowDimensions().height;
```

Note: `useWindowDimensions` is only available from React Native 0.61.0: https://reactnative.dev/blog/2019/09/18/version-0.61

Comment: I can't use that in expo-web but works fine in mobile

Comment: useWindowDimensions seems to only be callable from the main function, not in StyleSheet where I set the dimensions of all my stuff.  How do use the results from useWindowDimensions in StyleSheet?  The official doc example doesn't show how to do this.  Thanks!

Comment: @rfii You can call useWindowDimensions and save the width/height value and then pass that into a function that returns a style sheet object. `const myStyle = (deviceHeight, deviceWidth) => return Stylesheet.create({ max-width: deviceWidth, max-height: deviceHeight })`

Comment: @rfii @micnguyen you can also put the style directly into the component without creating an additional Stylesheet. For example if you want a text that adapts its size to the screen width, you can try: `<Text style={fontSize:useWindowDimensions().width/10}>Title</Text>`
If you already have a Stylesheet, you can also use both like that: `<Text style={[styles.title,{fontSize:useWindowDimensions().width/10}]}>Title</Text>`

Comment: `Stylesheet.create` is not needed. You can just `const style = useMemo(() => ({...style}), [])`

Comment: `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Comment: @Dee: This was just a code snippet. You should put the last 2 lines into the body of your component for it to work.

Answer (score 26):

React Native Dimensions is only a partial answer to this question, I came here looking for the actual pixel size of the screen, and the Dimensions actually gives you density independent layout size.

You can use React Native Pixel Ratio to get the actual pixel size of the screen.

You need the import statement for both Dimenions and PixelRatio

```
import { Dimensions, PixelRatio } from 'react-native';
```

You can use object destructuring to create width and height globals or put it in stylesheets as others suggest, but beware this won't update on device reorientation.

```
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
```

From React Native [Dimension](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions#docsNav) Docs:

> Note: Although dimensions are available immediately, they may change (e.g due to >device rotation) so any rendering logic or styles that depend on these constants >should try to call this function on every render, rather than caching the value >(for example, using inline styles rather than setting a value in a StyleSheet).

[PixelRatio](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio) Docs link for those who are curious, but not much more there.

To actually get the screen size use:

```
PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(width);
```

or if you don't want width and height to be globals you can use it anywhere like this

```
PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(Dimensions.get('window').width);
```

Comment: yes, this is the physical dimensions, tks

Answer (score 25):

If you have a Style component that you can require from your Component, then you could have something like this at the top of the file:

```
const Dimensions = require('Dimensions');

const window = Dimensions.get('window');
```

And then you could provide `fulscreen: {width: window.width, height: window.height},` in your Style component. Hope this helps

Answer (score 10):

React Native comes with "Dimensions" api which we need to import from 'react-native'

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
```

Then,

```
<Image source={pic} style={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').height}}></Image>
```

Answer (score 4):

Only two simple steps.

1. `import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'` at top of your file.
2. `const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');`

now the window screen height is stored in the height variable.

Comment: Not sure why you've just replied with the same answer? What does this really add?

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered `react-native-responsive-screen` [repo here](https://github.com/marudy/react-native-responsive-screen).  Found it very handy.

> react-native-responsive-screen is a small library that provides 2 simple methods so that React Native developers can code their UI elements fully responsive. No media queries needed.
>
> It also provides an optional third method for screen orienation detection and automatic rerendering according to new dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

First get Dimensions from react-native

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
```

then

```
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

in `windowWidth` you will find the width of the screen while in `windowHeight` you will find the height of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The latest method from 2020 is to use **useWindowDimensions**

the way i implemented it-

1. make a global.js file and set window width and height as global variables

```
    const WindowDimensions= (()=>{
    global.windowWidth = useWindowDimensions().width;
    global.windowHeight = useWindowDimensions().height;
    return (<></>);
    })
```

2. in App.js file,import window dimensions and add it to return block
3. use width and height everywhere as *global.windowHeight* and *global.windowWidth*

**using global variables** is not a good design pattern. but this thing works

Answer (score 1):

```js
    import {useWindowDimensions, Dimensions} from 'react-native'


let width1= useWindowDimensions().width // Hook can be called only inside functional component, tthis is dynamic
let width2=Dimensions.get("screen").width
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `react-native-responsive-dimensions` might help you a little better on your case.

You can still get:

device-width by using and `responsiveScreenWidth(100)`

and

device-height by using  and `responsiveScreenHeight(100)`

You also can more easily arrange the locations of your absolute components by setting margins and position values with proportioning it over 100% of the width and height

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a component and using it by importing it into the file you need.

```
import {Dimensions, PixelRatio} from "react-native";

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get("window");

const wp = (number) => {
    let givenWidth = typeof number === "number" ? number : parseFloat(number);
    return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel((width * givenWidth) / 100);
};

const hp = (number) => {
    let givenHeight = typeof number === "number" ? number : parseFloat(number);
    return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel((height * givenHeight) / 100);
};

export {wp, hp};
```

Now, you should use it.

```
import { hp, wp } from "../<YOUR PATH>";

  buttonContainer: {
    marginTop: hp("2%"),
    height: hp("7%"),
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
    width: wp("70%"),
    backgroundColor: "#1C6AFD",
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: wp("3.5%"),
    color: "#dddddd",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontFamily: "Spartan-Bold",
  }
```

That way, you will make your design responsive. I suggest using simple pixels in the styling of circle things like avatar images, etc.

In other cases, the above code wraps components according to the density pixels of the screen.

**If you have any better solution, please comment.**

Answer (score 0):

First, you must import Dimensions from 'react-native'

```
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions  } from "react-native";
```

after that, you can save width and height in variables:

```
const windowsWidth  = Dimensions.get('window').width

const windowsHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height
```

them you could use both as you need, i.e. in styles:

```
 flexDirection: windowsWidth<400 ? 'column' : 'row',
```

Remember this, your object styles is outside your component, so the cariable declaration must be outside your component too. But if you need it inside your component, no problem, can use it:

```
<Text> Width: { windowsWidth  }</Text>

<Text> Height: { windowsHeight }</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get device width and height in React Native,  by the following code:

```
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Dimensions` API is discouraged in favor of the `useWindowDimensions` hook as it does not provide the updated values of `height` and `width` when the device orientation changes while using the app.

For instance, the dimensions of an iPhone 14 pro in portrait mode are `{ height: 852 width: 393 }`, while in landscape mode, they become `{ height: 393 width: 852 }`. The `Dimensions` API fails to inform of this change which can potentially break the styling of application.

The recommended solution is to use the `useWindowDimensions` hook provided by `react-native` which observes the window's dimensions update.
As quoted by the [official React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions)

> useWindowDimensions is the preferred API for React components. Unlike Dimensions, it updates as the window's dimensions update. This works nicely with the React paradigm.

**Common challenges with useWindowDimensions**

As we all know that

> Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

So, the dimension returned by the `useWindowDimensions` doesn't fall within the global `Stylesheet` scope. To address this, consider defining the `Stylesheet` within a function that contains the `useWindowDimensions` call, returning the `styles` object.

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const styles = useStyle();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Hello, React Native!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const useStyle = () => {
  const { height: deviceHeight, width: deviceWidth } = useWindowDimensions();

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    text: {
      fontSize: deviceWidth > 380 ? 24 : 18,
      marginBottom: deviceHeight > 380 ? 20 : 10,
    },
  });

  return styles;
}

export default MyComponent;
```