# marginTop create problems for subview

Tags: css, react-native, margin

I have one view in which other image is there. when I give

```
marginTop:'10%'
```

to view subview images is not displaying in that view.
Any solution

Comment: I have never seen it in apostrophes, try to remove them so it is like marginTop: 10%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React-Native we have an Option called Dimensions ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33807375/8943429))

and here's what I do :

```
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
[...]

const DeviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
class YourClass extends React.Component {
  //render and return
  //DeviceWidth*0.9 = 90%
  <View style={{marginTop: DeviceWidth*0.1}}></View>
}
```

give it a try